# rattle "Info" Score in Description of the dataset

Tags: r, rattle

Running descriptive statistics in rattle and need to know what "Info" is in the results. Have not been able to find any information in the vignette. Here is an example of what I'm speaking of:

```
Variable1 
      n missing  unique    Info    Sum    Mean 
  89588       0       2    0.61   25735  0.2873
```

We believe it is a score of 0 to 1, but we are unable to find the exact definition.

Comment: Which rattle command did you use to get the output given above?  Can you supply a bit more context, e.g. a code snippet or data?

Comment: Joy - the rattle GUI has been called with the rattle() function. The dataset has been loaded and under the "explore" tab, we have opted to "describe" the data. The output for one of our variables is in the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The describe function used in Rattle comes from the package HMisc.

In the documentation of HMisc::describe this is said about Info:

> For numeric variables, describe adds an item called Info which is a
>   relative information measure using the relative efficiency of a
>   proportional odds/Wilcoxon test on the variable relative to the same
>   test on a variable that has no ties. Info is related to how continuous
>   the variable is, and ties are less harmful the more untied values
>   there are. The formula for Info is one minus the sum of the cubes of
>   relative frequencies of values divided by one minus the square of the
>   reciprocal of the sample size. The lowest information comes from a
>   variable having only one unique values following by a highly skewed
>   binary variable. Info is reported to two decimal places.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I needed.

Comment: @Phiver, any thoughts on the practical implications of the measure?